# How to execute in cucumber one file have some list of features

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Case 1:

File1.properties/txt

Test1.feature

Test2.feature

Test3.feature

Answer (score 0):

Create runner file and specify all the features to be executed in that

Comment: Could you link some documentation / example with you answer please?

Comment: Bro I want to run using cli